# Typo3 rewrite old dynamic page with page id to new page with page id in htaccess - error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, typo3

I had to setup a new server which in many cases has the same content as the old one. Many links (ids) still point to the old site which need to be rewritten to the new page id.

<strike>I am currenty not using RealURL *(but will once the 'core' works)*.</strike>

**Example links:**

```
Old: http://www.example.com/cms/index.php?id=400
New: http://www.example.com/cms/index.php?id=7
```

So, the old page id does not exist on the new site.
I have setup an .htaccess **on the root level** of the site. *(There is also another .htaccess of Typo3 installation which resides in **/cms/** - so one level down)*

The .htaccess I have setup is:
**.htaccess: in site root "/"** *(not the one in "/cms/")*

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{query_STRING} ^id=400(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/cms/index.php?id=7 [R]
```

All I get is a Typo3 Page Not Found (404) error (despite clearing cache etc). 
The Typo3 log shows:

> Core: Exception handler (WEB): Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: #1301648780: The requested page does not exist! ...

It seems that my rewrite rule is not being processed? 
Any help would be great.

Many thanks

Comment: Is there a specific reason for not using realUrl? Using raw uids for pages, categories, records etc. is very fragile as these might diverge across instances. Not only old site / new site but also development vs production instance. Adding an abstraction layer is a good idea. For urls this would be realUrl.

Comment: realURL is already on my list and definitely something to come as the next step. However, it also adds an additional layer of abstraction and complexity which I deliberately wanted to exclude at this stage (of development - that's why I mentioned it) till the core works the way I want. Thanks @sven

Comment: does the link `http://www.example.com/cms/index.php?id=7` work when not redirected from htaccess? (use @username - so the user see you answered to his comment)

Comment: @nbar thanks. Yes, the link to rewrite to works and page exist. Anything wrong with the syntax? The .htaccess I am modifying is the one in site root `/` . I guess the problem may be that there is also the one in the 'typo3 root' folder `/cms/` . I tried to add my rewrite rule under the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` section in there but that did not work either.

Comment: I am not sure what `/cms` folder you mean, as typo3 dont have such a folder. what typo3 version you use? also you can easy check if your rewrite rule works, just check if you get redirected to the right url.

Comment: Typo3 is installed to run from a subdir, which is `/cms` in my case, which is one level down from site root.